# strcat adds second parameter twice

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, strcat

```
class Vars{
    public:
    char *appData = getenv("AppData");
    string datadir = strcat(appData, "\\Bob");
};


cout << v.datadir;
```

outputs `"C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\Bob\Bob"`

instead of "`C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\Bob"`

It always adds the second parameter twice. How come?

Comment: Please remove the mock-class-look of the sample code. It isn't legal to initialise member variables using functions.

Comment: what does cout << v.appData return?

Comment: @RobH: actually, it is perfectly legal in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

"The string pointed by the pointer returned by this function shall not be modified by the program." Changing the value like you did (by strcat) leads to unpredictable behavior. The solution it to simply copy the immutable given string to a `string` and do the concatenation there.

What about making a new public function that does this:

```
string datadir(getenv("AppData"));
datadir += "\\Bob";
```

This is pre-C++11 code.

Comment: Oh... I still don't quite understand why, but it works, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are modifying memory that you should not be.  You get a pointer from [`getenv`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/), but that is pointing to memory that you do not control (emphasis mine).

> The pointer returned points to an internal memory block, whose content or validity may be altered by further calls to getenv (but not by other library functions).
>
> The string pointed by the pointer returned by this function *shall not be modified by the program*. Some systems and library implementations may allow to change environmental variables with specific functions (putenv, setenv...), but such functionality is non-portable.

By calling `strcat(appData, "\\Bob");` you are writing `\Bob` into a piece of memory you do not control.  The operating system may decide to do any number of things with it.  As has already been pointed out by @Liviu, it is much better to take a copy of the original value and append to that.

```
std::string appData( getEnv("AppData" ) );
appData += "\\Bob";
```

Comment: Oh... I was concatenating something to a pointer? I'm still not so familiar with the * before names and stuff, but I can understand how writing data to an 'unallocated' part of the memory can cause trouble... Thanks!